# What is this short plant with little blue flowers?

Tags: identification, wildflowers

It is all over the garden, this short plant with little blue flowers. I a kind of like it, but what is it? The yard will be mowed soon, is it wise to move at least some of them to the corner for wide flowers, and let it grow?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Vivid a weed is only a plant out of place.

Answer (score 5):

It's a speedwell, most likely slender speedwell or Veronica filiformis; it is a common lawn weed in Europe, along with one or two other similar ones, V. chaemedrys, V.  serpyllifolia and V. hederifolia. Slender speedwell is a highly invasive plant and  is not usually planted in borders because it's difficult to control; this is also true of the others mentioned. Image in this link, along with other common lawn weeds, and recommendations for control http://www.lawnhealth.co.uk/lawn-weeds/identification/

Comment: I would say *Veronica persica*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the link to the photos of common weeds. The plants in my pictures seems to be a Veronica, but their flower color is not exactly the same as the color of say Veronica filiformis. It is a very clear (without components of purple, red, yellow, etc) blue color, I happen to like it a lot. Too bad it is considered a weed.

Comment: By the way, somebody is selling a similar Veronica for $119! https://www.gardenerdirect.com/buy-plants-online/3411/Veronica-Spreading/Veronica-umbrosa-Georgia-Blue-Georgia-Blue-Speedwell

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Another contribution to the diversity of my weeds. ;) :D

Comment: Thanks for the link - what a price,so expensive! But Veronica umbrosa is a little better behaved so can be used in borders, needs cutting back hard once  a year see here https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/details?plantid=5383

Comment: There are many beautiful veronica. Especially the one with racemes (terminal flowers). I do not consider them weeds (stolonifer, radicant, but easy to remove on vegetable garden) @VividD: I think you have also a Geranium (true/European one). Your "wild garden" looks like my garden.

Comment: In any case, you should solve the identification: your Veronica has glandular hairs (Bamboo answer) or just simple hairs (my comment).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I thinks it is Veronica persica too, after some research. It is funny that it has nutritional and medicinal values: http://soilbeneath.blogspot.rs/2015/07/edible-weeds-plant-identification.html  Can you perhaps add an answer, since you mentioned it first?